# change radcombobox button color

Tags: asp.net, combobox, telerik

I use VS2010, C# in my ASP.NET web app, I'm using RadCombobox (telerik), how can I change its button (the part that contains downside arrow), also I want to change the button hover color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using Telerik ASP.NET AJAX toolkit you are able to change appearance of Rad controls by changing their skins.
You can select skin from the list of existing skins:

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/combobox-appearance-skins.html

You can also create your own skin using steps under followin link:

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/combobox-appearance-creating-custom-skins.html

Similar changes may be done to other Telerik controls.